# Find UNICODE or not using Javascript

Tags: javascript, unicode

We are designing a SMS send form where users can type any character they want.  The system should determine what type of character they type and based on that it will decide the type of the message and charge the user for SMS credts.  This form is going to be used by all over the world.

I am trying this using Javascript.  I count the number of characters and loop through each character.  If any of the character is double byte (> 255) then I determine it is a UNICODE or else it is a plain ASCII text.

I am not sure whether I am doing in the right way.

Recently one of the user tried the below and he claimed that the system has not deducted as UNICODE.  I got surprised that all these characters are less than 255 and I doubt my logic whether am I doing correct.

```
Sævar Davíðssson. ÆÝÐÞ
```

Can someone guide me please.

Answer (score 0):

Because of how various sms systems handle characters, you might have to create a **whitelist** in order to know what people will or will not get charged for.

Some carriers even charge differently depending on whether they're going to other carriers as well, so it can get fairly complex.

And if that wasn't bad enough, some carriers don't use pre-defined standards for their character sets. And several (especially internationally) use different and conflicting standards for character encoding.

Especially using JavaScript if you don't have the same character encoding as the carrier you'll run into problems figuring out what's legal to use.

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you mean by a whitelist.  I understand that each carrier has its own way to identify UNICODE and charge the customer and it may be difficult to write a generic way.  According to UNICODE standards, is the above is UNICODE or not?

Comment: A whitelist is a list of what counts as something. In this case you would probably want a STANDARD list that identified non-UNICODE characters, since that would be smaller than identifying all UNICODE characters. But not all carriers use the Unicode standard, so you can't rely on it if you want to make an international system that will interface with other sms carriers.

Comment: An additional thing to know is that some Unicode characters exists specifically to support non-standard sms characters of some carriers. For example check out the Unicode Emoji characters that are considered basic characters for some Japanese carriers: [http://www.unicode.org/faq/emoji_dingbats.html](http://www.unicode.org/faq/emoji_dingbats.html)

Answer (score 0):

The original [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) standard only defines 7-bit characters. There are a variety of 8-bit character encodings expanding on ASCII. One of the most popular ones is [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) ("latin-1", also mostly coincident with the windows codepage 1252). This adds a lot of western european language characters to the 7-bit ASCII set, including the ones in your example string.